# Make chain img.onload with img.src to Image() object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a function able to read array of "links of images" with foreach(item) iteration. In each iteration I am trying to: load image in an `Image()` object, and in the onload event to get properties (`naturalWidth` & `naturalHeight`) and paste it in the DOM as background of `<DIV>`.

However `img.onload` is asynchronous and before onload event pastes ones all iterations will pass.

How can I make continuous chain of img.onload and changing of img.src in each iteration?

```js
function singleGrid() {
  galdiv1.className = galClassList;

  function imgFill() {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        var nHeight = this.naturalHeight;
        var nWidth = this.naturalWidth;
        var res = nWidth / nHeight;
        console.log("image source: " + arr[i] + ", naturalWidth: " + nWidth + "px, naturalHeight: " + nHeight + "px");
        blockres = width * res;
        var div = divCreate(blockres);
        galdiv1.append(div);
      };
      img.src = item;##
      Heading##
    }, this);
  }
  imgFill();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to load all of your images and then append them to the DOM?

Comment: @MrSmith Yap. I want to load previously all images to get properties of Image() of each image naturalWidth and naturalHeight. Thatfor to calculate background width and height of each DIV where i will append this image.
I can i send you the screenshot of how it now works in chrome with Inspector code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imageURLS = [];
var imageTags = [];

// Runs once when all images are loaded
function onAllImagesLoaded() {

}

// Individual image loaded Successfully
function onImageLoad() {
    this.hasLoaded = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < imageTags.length; ++i) {
        if (!imageTags[i].hasLoaded) {
            return; // Exit the function if any image hasn't loaded yet
        }
    }

    onAllImagesLoaded();
}

// Individual image failed to load
function onImageError() {
    console.warn("Error: image " + this.id + " could not be retrieved");
    this.hasLoaded = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < imageTags.length; ++i) {
        if (!imageTags[i].hasLoaded) {
            return;
        }
    }

    onAllImagesLoaded();
}

function loadImages() {
    var newImageTag = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLS.length; ++i) {
        newImageTag = new Image();
        newImageTag.id = i; // Give each Image a unique identifier (Helps to find ones that don't load properly if you have any problems)
        newImageTag.hasLoaded = false; // Add new 'hasLoaded' flag
        newImageTag.onload = onImageLoad; // Set event handlers, It's better to use an existing function instead of an inlined one
        newImageTag.onerror = onImageError; // This is because an inlined function will create a closure when called
        newImageTag.src = imageURLS[i]; // This starts the async loading
        imageTags.push(newImageTag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to release this inside) Thank you for time spent on me
if someth will go wrong try to comment